# Windows 10 - Run a command when connecting to a device, say, a dock or monitor [Automate]

Tags: windows-10, command-line, multiple-monitors, powershell, docking-station

In Windows 10, is there a way to run cmd/powershell commands automatically when PC is connected to a particular device like a dock? (Like connecting a particular device triggers a command)

I want to do something like this-

```
If [device1 connected] -> Run Command A
If [device1 disconnected] -> Run Command B
If [device2 connected] -> Run Command C
...
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible using event triggering see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/06ceb3ff-0787-4df7-8992-53dc2b4a517b/get-dockingundocking-event?forum=ITCG and https://www.mundhenk.org/detecting-laptop-dock/ for some example logic. I'd turnt he vbscript logic example in the one post to PowerShell once I confirmed the specific event by docking and undocking the laptop and./or monitors, etc. See if you can whip up some simple test logic with some of this and see how it goes. Only one way to do it, and that's to do it. Get at it!!

Comment: This might still work with Win 10 too, so test some things with it or do more digging with some of these quick tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in general you can do it using Task Scheduler `taskschd.msc`. You can choose a task depending on an event (see `eventvwr.msc`).

More information is needed about the devices to give you a more specific answer. But you can find tons of examples yourself with a simple web search search, e.g. with those keywords `windows event connect device` you'll get [this result](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/41475-disconnect-connect-events.html). Just be more details on your devices...